# Ajax page is reloading after storing data

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am triyng to save data but my page is reloading with json message on next page, how can i stop reloading page.

**Ajax Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $("#add-data").submit(function (event)  {
event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Added");


            },
        });
    });
});
```

**Submit Button:**

```
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg shadow-lg rounded" value="ADD" id="add-data"> <span class=" fa fa-plus"> </span> ADD</button>
```

**Store Controller:**

after saving which is working fine:

```
return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'New esecond has been saved'
        ]);
```

Comment: Make the button type `button` instead of `submit`.

Comment: i have bootstrap validation set to required, if i change type="button", validation doesn't work, and button sends not post request.

Comment: I think you are using Laravel, we can use `Validator` provided by Laravel to validate everything.

Comment: @Rob that is also there, but when my request goes to server i get blank fields with error.

Comment: You have to change the button type to `button` and then you will not get blank fields with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead of prevent default. The reload happen, because you use form submit event.

`$('#add-data').submit(false);`

If you want to use prevent default, then use click event of the submit button to perform the action.

```
$("#add-data").click(function (event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "teachers",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Added");
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: i am still getting same response on next page.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of you are trying to post the data to form . 
If you use `button type = "submit"` it will redirect you to somewhere .
You should avoid using `type = "submit"` .
Instead use the `type = "button"`

```
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg shadow-lg rounded" value="ADD" id="add-data"> <span class=" fa fa-plus"> </span> ADD</button>
```

And achieve it by using click event of the button .

then get it in jquery .

```
$("#add-data").click(function (event)  {
    //Your code here 
}
```

Comment: i have bootstrap validation set to required, if i change type="button", validation doesn't work, and button sends not post request.

Answer (score 0):

Add "return false;" in the end of your submit callback..

As "add-data" is ID of your button, for your example it couldn't retrieve a submit event. That's because it submitted and didn't prevented.

So you can write something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function (event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ ... });

    return false; // <<< THE THING
});
```

Or just do that with binding an click event on button (not for submit event on button)

```
$("#add-data").click(function (event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

With this you can leave button type, and don't need to change that to type="button".

Comment: Yeah ! this one is nice . But this is not the preferred way in html . This one is not about form or submission . This is about jquery . So no need for the button type `submit`

Comment: I'm agree, but when dev don't want to change that, he want to just do that on submit event actually, then this can help him. We don't know what he did with form in other parts. So that's bcause I've mentioned about button type changing.

Comment: i am still getting same response on next page.

Comment: ah, sorry, you just didn't showed form html, so I thought that the form id is "add-data", but I just saw that the "add-data" is id of your button. It means that you didn't retrieved a submit event, so because it always submitted. So you have 3 ways now.
1. replace $('#add-data').submit(...);    to   $('form').submit(...);
2. replace $('#add-data').submit(...);    to   $('#add-data').click(...);
3. or just change the button type

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dataType: 'json'` as you're already returning JSON otherwise your button seems perfect.

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $("#add-data").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Added");


            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i am still getting same response on next page.